# Ruby: Variable as tablename

Tags: ruby, variables, tablename

I am looking for a way to get a variable being used as a tablename.

As example actually it looks like this:

```
@user = User.new
```

*but*, can I do this like

```
wrktablename = "User"
@my_table = wrktablename.new
```

Please note, that *wrktablename* really can be different values for the table name.

And in addition just to mention: I do not have the model name or the table name outside the variable.
But I need to use all functions like `wrktablename.new`and `wrktablename.find`and so on.

Answer (score 5):

To instantiate an object based on a class name that is in a variable, you can use `Object.const_get(wrktablename).new`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ruby on Rails, you can do it this way:

```
"class name".constantize.new
```

Comment: I do not see a variable here? What is the syntax with a variable? Is it like
`wrktablename.constantize.new`

Comment: Exactly as you write.